# How to set user input into a variable?

Tags: shell, variables, input

How to ask the user for their name and save it to a variable?

This is all I have done:

```
echo –n “What is your name?”
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `read` command:

```
# save user name to variable `name`
read -p 'what is your name? ' name

# print it
echo $name
```

Comment: Thanks, would you know how to display a welcome message to the user?